# Using Case Break to convert string to int C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, return, case, break

I'm trying to convert string to int. I think I have it right, but what else do I need to do? Under "Break" I get a green line saying "unreachable code detected". Also, what do I tell it to return? I put a random number after return, because I have blanked on what I should ask it to return.

```
namespace BattleShip.UI
{
    class TranslateNumberToLetter
    {
       public int NumberToLetter(string Letter)
       {
           switch (Letter)
           {
              case "A":return 1;
                 break;
              case "B": return 2;
                 break;
              case "C": return 3;
                 break;
              case "D": return 4;
                 break;
              case "E": return 5;
                 break;
              case "F": return 6;
                 break;
              case "G": return 7;
                 break;
              case "H": return 8;
                 break;
              case "I": return 9;
                 break;
              case "J": return 10;
                 break;
              default: return -100;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: as you return before the break, you definitely could omit it

Comment: 42 is universally good return value :) .. How SO should know what would you want to return from function? Answerable portion about "unreachable code" is [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643661/unreachable-code-detected-in-case-statement).

Comment: Side note: NumberToLetter is strange name converting letter to number...

Answer (score 2):

```
public int NumberToLetter(string Letter)
{
    if ("ABCEDFGHIJ".Contains(Letter))
        return "ABCEDFGHIJ".IndexOf(Letter) + 1;
    return -100;
}
```

Comment: Varocarbas, thank you.. I'll try this out.