# Switch value outside of function?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to get the value `alpha` and `beta` displayed OUTSIDE a switch, but the compiler throws [Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0162](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0162?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0162))
 (Unreachable code detected).
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```cs
        private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string alpha;
            byte beta = 0;

            alpha = comboBoxAlpha.Text;

            switch (alpha)
            {
                case "charlie":
                    beta = 1;
                    return;

                default:
                    beta = 0;
                    return;
            }

            if (beta == 0)
            {
                label1.Text = alpha;
            }
            else label1.Text = beta;
        }
```

Comment: _return_ ends the current method and returns to the caller. Nothing after return will be executed (unless in a _finally_ block). You should replace _return_ with _break_ if you want to reach the if condition

Comment: ^ That worked. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary. There are many duplicates on this situation. Instead I really suggest you to read some introductory text on C# because the problem is caused by a bit of basic knowledge missing here

Comment: Here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643661/unreachable-code-detected-in-case-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need in that complex code. As fas as I can see, you want `"1"` on `"cahalie"` and `comboBoxAlpha.Text` otherwise.

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (comboBoxAlpha.Text == "charlie")
    label1.Text = "1";
}
```

Or even

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
  label1.Text = comboBoxAlpha.Text == "charlie" ? "1" : comboBoxAlpha.Text;
```

The problem in your code is in `return` instead of `break`: `returns` return from the method, when `break`
just breaks the `switch`:

```
    private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string alpha;
        byte beta = 0;

        alpha = comboBoxAlpha.Text;

        switch (alpha)
        {
            case "charlie":
                beta = 1;
                break;    // Just break (jump out of) switch

            default:
                beta = 0;
                break;    // Just break (jump out of) switch 
        }

        if (beta == 0)
        {
            label1.Text = alpha;
        }
        else label1.Text = beta;
    }
```

Comment: It appears to me that it should be `label1.Text = comboBoxAlpha.Text == "charlie" ? "1" : comboBoxAlpha.Text`.